# Single Login for Multiple Sites

Tags: php, session, cookies, single-sign-on

I want to sync login functionality.

If a user logs in from one site, then that user automatically logs in to the other site as well.

I have sent a curl request to my other domain with email and password field, and all works well until now.

We get a success message in response, but when we open the site in the browser, then user is not logged in.

```
$value['email'] = "email";
$value['password'] = "password";

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$content = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

On server side `$_SESSION['logedin_user_id']`
We just set the session of logged-in user but when we open the url in browser then  `$_SESSION['logedin_user_id']` is empty.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: how do you check if the user is looged in?

Comment: What research have you done? There are lots of examples, libraries, tutorials on the internet

Comment: If you don't show the server-side session handling code, probably nobody will be able to answer that question.

Comment: @Binarus: Serverside info edit.

Answer (score 0):

Change code on this:

```
$value['email'] = "email";
$value['password'] = "password";

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($value));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$content = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

**http_build_query($value)** will format your array to query string. Info - [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php)